# How can I make this loop async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to get it so that while my loop is going on, the program will still run, I've tried using async/await combo but had no success. How should I be doing this so that the program will run smoothly while the loop runs at the same time?
the Btc value is sent to a label which updates what the value is

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public static class Program
{
    public static string Btc;

    public static void SendRequest()
    {
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?");
            using (var response = req.GetResponse())
                while (true)
                {
                    var html = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    Btc = Regex.Match(html, "\"BTC\",\"currency\":\"USD\",\"amount\":\"([^ \"]*)\"}").ToString();
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                }
        }
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        SendRequest();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Using the `async` method modifier and the `await` operator with methods like ReadToEnd**Async**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by using the `async` method modifier and the `await` operator with methods like `ReadToEndAsync`, and `GetResponseAsync`.  You do this by *never* calling `Thread.Sleep` which blocks the calling thread.

```
public static string Btc;

public static async Task SendRequestAsync()
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/prices/USD/spot?");
    using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
        while (true)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var html = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                Btc = Regex.Match(html, @"""BTC"",""currency"":""USD"",""amount"":""([^ ""]*)""}").ToString();
            }
            await Task.Delay(300);
        }
}
```